# I am getting an Error Message i cannot manage to fix

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, twitter-bootstrap

> System.Web.HttpException: 'Control 'txtSearchFirstAider' of type 'TextBox' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server.'

I am getting this error and i have made sure that i placed it inside a   tag and I am not making use of any master pages. Can anyone assist.

This is my back end code. Making use of VB.Net

```
    Protected Sub btnExportPDF_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Panel.pdf")
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
        Dim sw As New StringWriter()
        Dim hw As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        pnlAllFirstAiders.RenderControl(hw)
        Dim sr As New StringReader(sw.ToString())
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document(PageSize.A4, 10.0F, 10.0F, 100.0F, 0.0F)
        Dim htmlparser As New HTMLWorker(pdfDoc)
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream)
        pdfDoc.Open()
        htmlparser.Parse(sr)
        pdfDoc.Close()
        Response.Write(pdfDoc)
        Response.End()
    End Sub
```

This is my front end code

```
<form runat="server">

<div class="col-6">
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchFirstAider" placeholder="search employee clock no . . . . ." ReadOnly="false" CssClass="form-control mb-2 mr-sm-2" TextMode="Search" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Label ID="lblSearchFirstAiderResult" Visible="false" CssClass="text-danger btn-block" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" Text="no results found !"></asp:Label>

</div>

</form>
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You are trying to add a textbox outside of a form. Where is your html so we can help?

Comment: I have placed my code inside the form tags with runat server

Comment: Yes you said this. I meant for you to share your markup here.

Comment: Please find my code above.

Comment: Your form doesn't have the ID property.

Comment: Thanks guys I have managed to fix the issue. There was a problem with the rendering and I just had to use a block of empty code that fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys for your input I have managed to fix the initial problem.